# How to avoid WPF to make Arrangements/Measurements on my own controls?

Tags: wpf

I have developed a 3D-engine in C# and I want it to be usable from within a WPF application through classes that can be used just like any other WPF Control.

### First implementation

I created a Panel (let's call it EnginePanel) that extends the Grid class, and a set of controls to put inside like SceneNodeControl, GeometryControl, etc... These controls inherit the FrameworkElement WPF class.

For the SceneNodeControl, I exposed a Children property (UIElementCollection) and overrode that Logical/Visual management methods so that they look inside this collection.

I also overrode the ArrangeOverride and MeasureOverride methods so that we call Arrange/Measure on each child of the SceneNodeControl and then return a constant Size of zero pixels.

This implementation works and allows me to use ItemsControl, ContentControl and DataTemplates to populate my scene graph with a classical MVVM pattern.

### Problem

My problem is that if I create a massive scene graph with hundreds of SceneNodeControls, the application dramatically slows down.

A quick check with the Visual Studio Profiler informed me that the Measure method from SceneNodeControl is responsible for 80% to 90% of the CPU usage (in terms of time spent).

OK, no problem. What I have to do is to remove these calculations that are too heavy and moreover useless in my case.

## Solution 1

I tried to simply remove the call to the Arrange/Measure methods on the children of the SceneNodeControl.

This does not work. As specified [in MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.measureoverride(v=vs.110).aspx), the implementations of these methods MUST call the Arrange/Measure on the children.

### Solution 2

Inherits the FrameworkContentElement. Indeed, this class does not have layouting algorithms.

But it does not have any Visual tree management, which makes it unusable with ItemsControls, ContentControl and DataTemplates.

### Other solutions

I don't have other solutions... so this is why I'm here now!

The question is How to avoid WPF to make Arrangements/Measurements on my own controls?

Thanks!

## Edit

### Solution 3

I found another solution to my problem (but it produces more and more questions).

My controls can inherit the DependencyObject class. In that way, it should be possible to use the DataContextes from other WPF controls and more generally their DependencyProperties.

Problem number 1: I cannot use the existing DataTemplate, ItemsControl and ContentControl classes, but I probably can reimplement them...

Problem number 2: I cannot tell a DependencyObject to be a 'parent' of another DependencyObject. I found some hacks that 'reflect' this class and expose hidden members to try to manage the InheritanceContext and InheritanceParent. But since no one seems to do that and since Microsoft obviously don't want us to use it, it's really hard...

I will probably open a new question about this second problem. (Edit: It's [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22053688/how-to-inherit-the-dependencyobject-class-and-make-dependencyproperties-working).)

## Edit: to focus my question

What I want is writing something like that:

```
<controls:SceneNodeControl NodeName="Root">
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding SceneNodes}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:SceneNodeViewModel}">
                <controls:SceneNodeControl NodeName="{Binding Name}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</controls:SceneNodeControl>
```

and, at runtime, don't execute Measure/Arrange algorithms on the SceneNodeControls but build their Logical/Visual trees.

And [here](http://loic-morvan.fr/WPFControls.zip) is my little test project.

Comment: I still think you're going about this in the wrong way... if you want to use WPF, then you'll have to follow it's rules. Without those two methods, your items just won't be rendered. There are alternatives though... what about data virtualization? Read the [Optimizing Performance: Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716879(v=vs.110).aspx) page on MSDN to see what else you can do to improve performance.

Comment: The point is I don't need these elements to be rendered, just updated. My EnginePanel uses these elements to populate a scene graph (another way to view the data) that is itself used to compute the final image rendered by the EnginePanel (with a little DirectX 9 trick). Finally, the only element that is rendered in WPF is the EnginePanel, not the SceneNodeControls nor GeometryControls. I just realized that what I want is just to use the Bindings on my controls and let WPF (maybe it's not WPF that does that) instantiate these controls with DataTemplates and ItemsControls/ContentControls.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want measure and Arrange affect the logic tree starting in NodeSceneControl and don't want to render it, just set its Visibility property to Visibility.Collapsed. This way, this node will be left out of the layout processing.

Comment: Good point! It does stop the execution of MeasureOverride and ArrangeOverride. But it does NOT allow me to use ItemsControl and DataTemplate in my SceneNodeControl. I use a UIElementCollection as the children of the SceneNodeControl: do I have to set special parameters on it? Or call some 'hidden' algorithms on these children to let the VisualTree and/or LogicalTree be constructed?

Comment: Why can't you use DataTemplate and ItemsControl. Maybe I'm missing something, but I don't see how the visibility state of a node can affect its logical tree.

Comment: Just try it. With the sample I just posted, the constructor of SceneNodeControl is called only once for the "Root" node. If I remove the Vibility.Collapsed flag, the constructor is passed 5 times (one for my root, and one for each SceneNodeViewModel in my SceneNodes). The visual tree is not build. And I don't know why :p

Comment: I posted the project where I test all we say on my original question. Fell free to test yourself. Thank you!