# How to inherit the DependencyObject class and make DependencyProperties working?

Tags: wpf

I want to make a set of controls that inherit the DependencyObject class. (For the story, I don't want to do operations of Measuring/Arranging in these controls but it's not the point here.)

I naively thought DependenciesProperties would directly work on these controls. This is not the case.

### First problem

Conceptually, since I don't update the parent of the DependencyObject, it's obvious the DependencyProperties cannot find their values from a parent and then properties like DataContext are not inherited.

I found a half solution for that:

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Windows;

namespace ControlsLibrary.Base
{
    public class FrameworkElement : DependencyObject
    {
        private static MethodInfo _setInheritanceParentMethod;

        static FrameworkElement()
        {
            // NOTE: Hack to expose a hidden method.
            _setInheritanceParentMethod = typeof(DependencyObject).GetMethod("SetInheritanceParent", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        }

        private delegate void SetInheritanceParentDelegate(DependencyObject obj);

        private readonly SetInheritanceParentDelegate _setInheritanceParent;

        private DependencyObject _inheritanceParent = null;

        public FrameworkElement()
        {
            // NOTE: Prefer the use of delegates rather than MethodInfo.Invoke.
            _setInheritanceParent = (SetInheritanceParentDelegate)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(SetInheritanceParentDelegate), this, _setInheritanceParentMethod);
        }

        public DependencyObject InheritanceParent
        {
            get { return _inheritanceParent; }
            set
            {
                if (_inheritanceParent != value)
                {
                    _inheritanceParent = value;

                    _setInheritanceParent(_inheritanceParent);
                }
            }
        }

        public object DataContext
        {
            get { return (object)GetValue(DataContextProperty); }
            set { SetValue(DataContextProperty, value); }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for DataContext.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty DataContextProperty =
            System.Windows.FrameworkElement.DataContextProperty.AddOwner(typeof(FrameworkElement), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.Inherits));
    }
}
```

With that solution, I was able to inherit the DataContext between two of my FrameworkElements

```
var parent = new FrameworkElement();
var child = new FrameworkElement();

Assert.AreEqual(null, parent.DataContext);
Assert.AreEqual(null, child.DataContext);

parent.DataContext = "Test";
Assert.AreEqual("Test", parent.DataContext);
Assert.AreEqual(null, child.DataContext);

child.InheritanceParent = parent;
Assert.AreEqual("Test", parent.DataContext);
Assert.AreEqual("Test", child.DataContext);

parent.DataContext = "Check";
Assert.AreEqual("Check", parent.DataContext);
Assert.AreEqual("Check", child.DataContext);

child.DataContext = "Test";
Assert.AreEqual("Check", parent.DataContext);
Assert.AreEqual("Test", child.DataContext);

child.InheritanceParent = null;
Assert.AreEqual("Check", parent.DataContext);
Assert.AreEqual("Test", child.DataContext);
```

and between a Wpf.FrameworkElement and one of my FrameworkElement.

```
var parent = new System.Windows.FrameworkElement();
var child = new ControlsLibrary.Base.FrameworkElement();
```

Great!

### Second problem

I tried with three of my FrameworkElements and it didn't work... The DataContext is inherited with two objects but not three objects...

```
var element0 = new FrameworkElement();
var element1 = new FrameworkElement();
var element2 = new FrameworkElement();

element1.InheritanceParent = element0;
element2.InheritanceParent = element1;
Assert.AreEqual("Test", element0.DataContext);
Assert.AreEqual("Test", element1.DataContext); // --> This one works.
Assert.AreEqual("Test", element2.DataContext); // --> But this one is null!!!
```

So I guess I did something wrong.

### Question

So the question is: How to inherit the DependencyObject class and make DependencyProperties working?

In other words: Did someone already 'hacked' the DependencyObject class? Can someone provide a full explanation of what I have to do to have a fully functional FrameworkElement?

Or is it dead?

If necessary, I can help finding out with other people how it works!

Thanks!

Comment: Why would you want to reinvent the wheel like this? What are you `really` trying to achieve? can you post a screenshot of what you need, and explain why using the relevant already implemented WPF UI elements is not an option?

Comment: See my post [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21971884/how-to-avoid-wpf-to-make-arrangements-measurements-on-my-own-controls) that explains what I want to do. Keep in mind that the goal of this question is not 'What I want to make' but 'How do I make that particular thing'. It's at least for my personal curiosity and if it's not the best way to do what I want in my other post, I don't care!